# Website Layout is Messed up

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulties creating separate containers for the header, body, and other sections of the website. I'm not sure where my code is incorrect, but the layout is not as planned. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>San Francisco | Downtown Parking Guide</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    </head>

    <body>
    <!-- Header -->
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="cf">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="logo" title="Home Page"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" title="Home Page" class="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="bar">|</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Downtown Parking List">Downtown Parking List</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    <!-- End Header -->
    <!-- Begin San Francisco Image -->
        <div class="container">

            <div id="sfpic">
                <h1>WELCOME TO THE</h1>
                    <div class="break1"></div>
                <h2>SAN FRANCISCO PARKING GUIDE</h2>
            </div>
    <!-- End San Francisco Image -->
    <!-- Begin Ad  -->      
                <div class="ad">
                    <h1>SPECIAL DEALS</h1>
                        <div class="break1"></div>
                            <h2>RESERVE</h2>
                        <h3>SAN FRANCISCO PARKING AND SAVE UP TO 70%</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="adbutton">RESERVE NOW</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End Ad -->
    <!-- Begin Text Below Picture & Add -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="break1"></div>
                <p>San Francisco is a cultural, commerical, and financial center in Northern California and the only consolidated city in Northern California. San Francisco is known as a popular tourist destination due to it's cool summers, fog, steep hills, eclectic mix of architecture and landmarks including the Golden Gate Bridge, cable cars, Alcatraz, and Chinatown.</p>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

CSS:

@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
html {
    background: #ffffff; }
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Times, serif;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto; }
@font-face { font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; src: url url(../Images/HelveticaNeue.ttf); } 
@font-face { font-family: "Avenir"; src: url(../Images/AvenirLTStd-Light.otf); }

/*--- Begin Header Section ---*/

.logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 30px 330px 0 20px;
    background-image: url(../Images/DPG-Logo.jpg) ;
    width: 406px;
    height: 28px;
}
/*micro-clearfix by Nicolas Gallagher http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/*/
/* For modern browsers */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table; }
.cf:after {
    clear:both; }
/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.cf {
    zoom:1; }
/*horizontal menu styles*/  
nav {
    background: #FFF }

ul, li {
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left; 
    }

ul {
    background: none;
    height: none; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

li {
    display: inline-block; 
}
li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: none;
    padding: 0;
    color: #8b9093;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 36px 0 0 30px;
}
li a:hover {
    color: #FE5A1D;
    }

li a:active {
    color: #d74c18;
}

.bar {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
a.bar:hover{
    color: #8b9093;
}
/*--- Need to Fix This ---*/
/*---Need to Fix This ---*/
/*--- End Header Section ---*/


/*--- Begin City Picture Section ---*/
.container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#sfpic {
    background-image: url(../Images/sf-downtown.jpg);
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0 ;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#sfpic h1 {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 425px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
#sfpic h2 {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0 ;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
.break1 {
    padding: 4px 0 0 0 ;
}
/*--- End City Picture Section ---*/

/*--- Begin Ad Section ---*/
.ad {
    background-image: url(../Images/sf-ad.jpg);
    float: left;
    width: 330px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0
}
.ad h1 {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
.break2 {
    padding: 0;
}
.ad h2 {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0px ;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
.ad h3 {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 0 0 0px ;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
.adbutton {
    background-image: url(../Images/button-reserve.jpg);
    height: 48px;
    width: 160px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 50px 0 0 90px;
    border:none;
}

.adbutton:hover {
    background-image: url(../Images/button-reserve-hover.jpg);  
}

.adbutton:active {
    background-image: url(../Images/button-reserve-click.jpg)   
}
/*--- End Ad Section ---*/

/*--- Begin First Text Section Below Pictures ---*/
.container p {

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44z5a055/

Comment: We're not mind readers. Tell us what you want and the error you're having.

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to get the logo on the top left with the nav links on the right. Below that should be the Picture with the "Welcome to... san fran. text inside. On the right side of that is the ad.. Below both of those paragraph text.

Comment: The errors i'm having is the nav links are falling below the logo, text is underneath the "welcome to... picture. and the ad is below the text.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there is unwanted space and margin and `color:#FFF`.. have removed some of them.
http://jsfiddle.net/44z5a055/

Answer (score 0):

just try the basic layout of the bootstrap. It will solve your problem.